# SQL Server Query with Derived Table Produces Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have a situaltion **similar** to this

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT *  
  FROM 
  Table1
)
```

I wonder why this gives an error

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Any help ? Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT *  
  FROM 
  Table1
) x
```

You need to give your derived table a name.

Comment: I wish the error message were more intuitive. Why can't it be `Derived table is missing an alias.`?

Comment: Yeah I had the same problem years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to add an alias. Run it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM Table1
) T
```

Just for the record, MySQL displays the following error given the same situation :)

> *Every derived table must have its own alias*

Comment: Just don't be fooled into believing that makes MySQL better. :-)

Comment: Never said that. Just made a simple comparison given the same problem. I know SQL Server has remarkable points, but simple parsing errors seem not to be its strongest points :)

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that it's easy to fix simple parsing errors. It's that decisions about errors were made long before anybody complained, and it's difficult to change an error message due to backward compatibility issues. In MySQL it's easy because it's cowboy open source. :-)

Answer (score 1):

And you can use the AS keyword to make it more readable

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table1 )  as table2
```